# What does qualify mean?

Tags: java, c++, computer-science

When reading articles, manuals, etc... about programming, i always come across the word `qualified`. like in java the fully qualified class name would be com.example.Class. Reading 
[this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm) article, defines the scope resolution operator `::` in C++ as being used to Qualify hidden names so you can still use them. Is there a definition for this ? Beccause it seems to be used in a different context each time.

Comment: So if you look at Narendra's quote, I think you can take it that to `qualify` is to eliminate ambiguity. Although N's answer only addresses the java `fully qualified class name` you state, I think `to eliminate ambiguity` fits to both examples you give.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In computer programming, a fully qualified name is an ***unambiguous name***
>   that specifies which object, function, or variable a call refers to
>   without regard to the context of the call. In a
>   hierarchical structure, a name is fully qualified when it "is complete
>   in the sense that it includes (a) all names in the hierarchic sequence
>   above the given element and (b) the name of the given element
>   itself." Thus fully qualified names explicitly refer to namespaces
>   that would otherwise be implicit because of the scope of the call.
>   While always done to eliminate ambiguity, this can mean different
>   things dependent on context.

[Source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name)

In short what it means is that,

You can have a class named `Math` in your project, but `Math` is already present in Java too.

So for unambiguously identifying which class you are actually referring to you need to qualify the name with package too:

```
java.lang.Math //refers to java class Math
org.myproject.Math //refers to your project Math class
```

Comment: when you think about it, every time i see it, it is being used to remove ambiguities.

Answer (score 3):

From Merriam Webster

> Full Definition of QUALIFY
>
> transitive verb
>   1
>   a :  to reduce from a general to a particular or restricted form :  modify
>   b :  to make less harsh or strict :  moderate
>   c :  to alter the strength or flavor of
>   d :  to limit or modify the meaning of (as a noun)
>   2
>   :  to characterize by naming an attribute :  describe 
>   3
>   a :  to fit by training, skill, or ability for a special purpose
>   b (1) :  to declare competent or adequate :  certify (2) :  to invest with legal capacity :  license

Clauses 1 and 2 apply. Java and C++ both have scoping/namespaces, and "qualify" means to introduce sufficient scopes to distinguish between potential candidates.

C.f.: If you have two classes with a member called "read".

```
class Foo {
    void read();
};

class Bar {
    void read();
};
```

In your implementation file, you will implement both functions. But if you wrote (C++)

```
void read() {}
```

This is valid, but it creates a function in the global namespace, rather than implementing one of the two functions. The same code written inside the class Foo definition would implement Foo::read.

So to implement our member functions outside the class definitions, we have to qualify - to reduce from general, to name the attribute of the container path - which read we are implementing.

```
void Foo::read() {}
void Bar::read() {}
```

The global namespace is "::", so you can even be explicit if you are trying to use that:

```
void ::read() {}  // note: this name is already taken by stdio's read() :)
```

Comment: "Given that the global namespace is anonymous", no, in C++ it isn't. "Anonymous namespaces" have a specific meaning, in particular they're distinct for each Translation Unit. The global namespace is the same namespace everywhere.