# Filling ArrayList with initialized Objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, null, fill

I have the  ArrayList deck in Class Deck.I want to  fill the ArrayList with Card objects.

Also I want to fill the attributes of the Card objects.

I added a for loop to see the results,and the ArrayList had 5 objects with NULL in name and 0 in value.

(FillDeck has been called in main function)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Deck {

    private ArrayList<Card> deck=new ArrayList();


      public Deck(){

    }


      public Deck(ArrayList<Card> deck ){

        this.deck = deck;

    }

          //hearts,spades,diamonds,clubs  
        Card card1 = new Card("A hearts",11,true);
        Card card2 = new Card("2 hearts",2,true);
        Card card3 = new Card("3 hearts",3,true);
        Card card4 = new Card("4 hearts",4,true);    
        Card card5 = new Card("5 hearts",5,true);




    public void filldeck(){





        deck.add(card1);       
        deck.add(card2);       
        deck.add(card3);      
        deck.add(card4);     
        deck.add(card5);       


          for (int i=0; i<deck.size(); i++){

              System.out.println(deck.get(i).getName());
              System.out.println(deck.get(i).getValue());


          }

    }


}




public class Card {


    private String name;
    private int value;
    private boolean samecard = true ;

    public Card(){

    }

    public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){

        name = this.name;
        value = this.value;
        samecard = this.samecard;
    }

    public String getName(){

        return name;
    }

    public int getValue(){

        return value;
    }

    public boolean getSamecard(){

        return samecard;
    }
}
```

Comment: You put up a bunch of (pretty lazily! formatted) code. And some requirements. But what is your question? That we digest all of that to the rest of your homework? Sorry, if you have a code problem, put up a [mcve].

Comment: You should be using `enum`s for a deck of cards.

Comment: man,I just asked a simple specific question. I never wanted to solve my "homework".If you dont want to help me,you are welcome not to!

Comment: That's not a good way to assign values inside the constructor of  Card class. use it like vice versa buddy.

Comment: @ParvizMakari how do you suggest to assign them my friend?

Comment: @Manolis like this.
this.name = name;
this.value = value;
this.samecard = samecard;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are seeing the default values of the fields. To fix that you have to actually assign the values e.g.

```
public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.samecard = samecard;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Card(String name, int value, boolean samecard)` has wrong implementation, you cannot assign the instance variable to the constructor parameter.

Just to be clear this is wrong: `name = this.name`

This is correct: `this.name = name`

This  is a correct implementation:

```
    public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.samecard = samecard;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your constructor inside of Card class, change In the constructor variables assignment to:

```
this.name = name;
this.value = value;
this.samecard = samecard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Contractor has a problem. It look's like this:

```
public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){
    name = this.name;
    value = this.value;
    samecard = this.samecard;
}
```

and it should be like this:

```
public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.samecard = samecard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are [qualifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803036/what-does-qualify-mean) the right side of the assignment and that is in this case incorrect:

```
public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){

    name = this.name;
    value = this.value;
    samecard = this.samecard;
}
```

it must be

```
public Card(String name,int value,boolean samecard){

    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.samecard = samecard;
}
```